# CSGO Jump throwing on negative aliases

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I know how "jump throw" works and also it's bind. However, I'm trying to make "jump throw" work only ON KEY RELEASE, instead of KEY DOWN, so that I can achieve the *cl_crosshairsize* technique as well (crosshair size changing alias) within the same key.

Usual "jump throw" bind:

```
alias "+jumpthrow" "+jump;-attack;"
alias "-jumpthrow" "-jump"
bind TARGET_KEY +jumpthrow
```

Desired "jump throw" bind:

```
alias "+jumpthrow" ""
alias "-jumpthrow" "+jump;-attack;-jump"
bind TARGET_KEY +jumpthrow
```

Unfortunately this does not work and I have no idea why, even if you set something on +jumpthrow (eg. say something).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `+jump` and `-jump` on the same bind. The game can't execute an action and stop it at the same time, so this kind of bind always breaks.

A partly working solution would be something like this:

```
alias "+jumpthrow" ""
alias "-jumpthrow" "+jump;-attack;"
bind TARGET_KEY +jumpthrow
```

This executes the jump and e.g. a grenade throw on key release as expected.

However, due to the nature of how binds work you need a `-jump` somewhere else, otherwise the game would sit on `+jump` forever. This is not a real issue, because gravity replaces the `-jump` eventually, but it's better to solve a problem rather than ignoring it.

You could solve this issue easily by

- jumping manually after executing the bind
- adding `-jump` to the binds of frequently used non-movement keys (e.g. `slot1`, `reload`, etc)

Comment: Curiously, you CAN have `-jump` on the same bind. For instance, try something like `bind "l" "+jump; -attack; -jump;"` and it'll work.
Indeed, I did "solve" it by adding the `-jump` to my 4 movement keys, however, there's another bug: it keeps spamming on console that some commands aren't recognized, even thought they are executed. Check it out: `bind "w" "+forward; -jump;"`. However, if you remove the `; ` at the end, it stops spamming and working. This is so weird.

Comment: @Henri this is strange indeed. It never worked for me. Having an empty ; at the end of a command should do nothing, so this is very strange. I'll do some tests later as this might just be a bug.